# Where can we get old versions of Android platform?

Tags: android, download

The old versions of Android can still be downloaded from  https://dl.google.com/android/ but you need to know the file name of the archive you're downloading (because Google has disable the index for the directory) . Does anyone have a list showing those names because I need to download Android SDK 2.2 (or 2.3) for Windows?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Android SDK 2.2 (or 2.3) for Windows".

The Android SDK itself is available for Windows, but that is not tied to Android versions like 2.2 or 2.3. You can download [the current Android SDK for Windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Then, you can download "obsolete" SDK Platform versions from the SDK Manager by checking the "Obsolete" checkbox:

[image: SDK Manager, Showing Obsolete Versions]